# Kivy how to update a widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

so I have a ScrollView that shows buttons based on a global list. It looks like this
[image]

To create this, I used this method

```
def create_scrollview(self, dt):
    global connectionList
    
    base = [i for i in connectionList]

    removeButton = ["X" for i in connectionList] 
     
    self.layout = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)

    self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter("height"))

    for element in base:

        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text=element, size=(50, 50),
                                 background_color = (.3, .3, .3, 1),
                                 size_hint=(1, None)))

        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text = 'X', size = (10, 10),
                                 size_hint = (.15, .1),
                                 background_normal = '',
                                 background_color = (1 , .5, .5, 1)))         
        
    self.scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
    
    self.scrollview.add_widget(self.layout)
    
    self.view.add_widget(self.scrollview)
```

So basically when I click a button, it needs to  trigger two functions, one that adds 'four' to the list, and one that calls this method.

```
    def resetScrollView(self):
   
    global connectionList
    
    base = [i for i in connectionList]

    removeButton = ["X" for i in connectionList] 
  
    for element in base:

        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text=element, size=(50, 50),
                                 background_color = (.3, .3, .3, 1),
                                 size_hint=(1, None)))

        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text = 'X', size = (10, 10),
                                 size_hint = (.15, .1),
                                 background_normal = '',
                                 background_color = (1 , .5, .5, 1)))            
    

    print(connectionList)
```

So basically, it prints the updated connectionList ('first','second','third','fourth')
But the UI isn't updated and stays the same. Can you guys tell me what to do to make the ScrollView mirror the connectionList (each button for each string on list)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to create is a scrollView of list elements, and when a new list element is added, the scrollview needs to be updated. It's simple but I can't figure it out